# Concat column name with data of first row, Python 3.6 Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to add data of first row of the dataframe to its column name & delete first row.

Source DataFrame:

```
2013K2  2013K3  2013K4  2013K5
ABC1    ABC2    ABC3    ABC4
324 5435    543 543
6543    543 657 765
765 876 876 9876
```

Need to rename column name as Column Name +'|'+ Data of First row:

```
2013K2|ABC1 2013K3|ABC2 2013K4|ABC3 2013K5|ABC4
324 5435    543 543
6543    543 657 765
765 876 876 9876
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIUC

```
df.columns=df.columns+'|'+df.iloc[0,:]
df.iloc[1:,]
Out[41]: 
0 2013K2|ABC1 2013K3|ABC2 2013K4|ABC3 2013K5|ABC4
1         324        5435         543         543
2        6543         543         657         765
3         765         876         876        9876
df=df.iloc[1:,]
df
Out[43]: 
0 2013K2|ABC1 2013K3|ABC2 2013K4|ABC3 2013K5|ABC4
1         324        5435         543         543
2        6543         543         657         765
3         765         876         876        9876
```

Comment: @faithon.gvr.py ah, yw~ happy coding

Answer (score 5):

You could do it like this, using `T` and `set_index`, then combining multiindex columns to a single column heading using `map` and `format`.

```
df_out = df.T.set_index(0, append=True).T

df_out.columns = df_out.columns.map('{0[0]}|{0[1]}'.format)

df_out
```

Output:

```
  2013K2|ABC1 2013K3|ABC2 2013K4|ABC3 2013K5|ABC4
1         324        5435         543         543
2        6543         543         657         765
3         765         876         876        9876
```

Comment: @faithon.gvr.py You're welcome.  Glad, I could help.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following one-liner:

```
In [148]: df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x+'|'+df.iloc[0][x]).iloc[1:]

In [149]: df
Out[149]:
  2013K2|ABC1 2013K3|ABC2 2013K4|ABC3 2013K5|ABC4
1         324        5435         543         543
2        6543         543         657         765
3         765         876         876        9876
```

Answer (score 0):

One can use simple `for` loop and other basic functions to create a new list of column names and change the dataframe:

```
newcols = []             # empty list to have new column names
for i in range(len(df.columns)):
    newcols.append(df.columns[i]+'|'+df.iloc[0,i])  # make and add new name to list
df.columns = newcols     # assign column names
df = df.iloc[1:,:]       # exclude first row

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  2013K2|ABC1 2013K3|ABC2 2013K4|ABC3 2013K5|ABC4
1         324        5435         543         543
2        6543         543         657         765
3         765         876         876        9876
```