# Merging two rows in pandas to one header cell per column

Tags: python, pandas

i have a table in pandas that looks like this:

| 0 | A | Another |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | header | header |
| 2 | First | row |
| 3 | Second | row |

and what i would like to have a table like this :

| 0 | A header | Another header |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | First | row |
| 2 | Second | row |

how can i merge cells 0 and 1 to one header column?

Comment: what is that column `0`? Is it actually the index of your DataFrame?

Comment: is `df.columns == ["A", "Another"]`?

Comment: @najeem  yes it is

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concat column name with data of first row, Python 3.6 Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48009878/concat-column-name-with-data-of-first-row-python-3-6-dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a question about that column `'0'`, if indeed it is one. But if it is not (and is just the index having been pasted slightly incorrectly), then I would do:

```py
newdf = df.iloc[1:].set_axis(df.columns + ' ' + df.iloc[0], axis=1)
>>> newdf
  A header Another header
1    First            row
2   Second            row
```